# Regular expression to match "Order by" sql syntax

Tags: regex

In SQL we can do:

```
.... ORDER BY col1 (ASC/DESC) , col2 (ASC/DESC) , .....
```

I'm trying to write a regular expression to capture that: (the $ at the end is to make sure the query is in a single line)

```
(^|\|\s*?)order\s+by\s+\w\s+(asc | desc)?(\s+,\w\s+(asc | desc)?)*$
```

Unfortunately , typing the string

```
"order by MyCol"
```

in https://regex101.com/ gives 0 results. Does anyone know where I went wrong?

Comment: What did you try to do at the begining with `(^|\|\s*?)` ?

Comment: The real syntax is actually `order by <expression> [ASC|DESC]` so theoretically you need to be prepared for `order by case when col_1 = 'Z' then 1 when col_1 = 'Y'  then 2 else 3 end`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed a few things:

```
order\s+by\s+\w+(\s+asc|\s+desc)?([\s,]*\w+(\s+asc|\s+desc)?)*$
```

Comment: It should be easily readable from left to right but if some part isn't obvious, please ask.

Comment: Thanks. Why do you have w+ after the by\s+ ?

Comment: @Shmoopy It's for the name of the column

Comment: Sorry, I meant why the + and not just w ?

Comment: because `\w` is just one char, `\w+` is one char or more

Comment: A more general expression would be `[\w\d\[\]\._]` in place of `\w` for column names.

Comment: Thanks! :) \s+ should be added in front...

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to use this one. It's slightly more general than Denys's answer - and I have to thank him for pointing me in the right direction to fix a mistake I was making.

```
ORDER \s+ BY \s+(\s*[a-z_\[][\w_\[\]\.]* (\s+COLLATE \s+ [a-z_\[][\w_\[\]\.]*)? (\s+(ASC|DESC))?) (\s*, (\s*[a-z_\[][\w_\[\]\.]* (\s+COLLATE \s+ [a-z_\[][\w_\[\]\.]*)? (\s+(ASC|DESC))?))*
```

The whitespace is only included for readability: remove it, or, if you use .NET Regex class, specify the `RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhiteSpace` option. In any case, make sure you're ignoring case and considering multiline matches.